# How to successfully add Eventgen App to Splunk

Tags: splunk

Having difficulty adding EventGen app to Splunk Enterprise instance per 
`Splunk 7 Essentials`.

https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/splunk-7-essentials/9781788839112/ - 10-day Free Trial to access book

Followed everything from the book, i.e

1. Install 60-trial of Splunk Enterprise on `C:/` (as opposed to `C:/Program Files`)
2. Went to `https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Splunk-7-Essentials-Third-Edition` and clicked the green button, "Clone or Download"
3. Extracted contents to C:/
4. Renamed extracted file to `SA-Eventgen`
5. Opened cmd prompt in Administrator mode and ran following command

`xcopy SA-Eventgen C:SplunketcappsSA-Eventgen /O /X /E /H /K`

However, **there is a deviation** in the next step.

The book says when you run

`dir C:SplunketcappsSA-Eventgen` from the command prompt, you should get

[image]

But when I run

`dir C:SplunketcappsSA-Eventgen` from the command prompt, I get

[image]

And when I restart Splunk instance and log in again, there is no indication that EventGen app has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Book has a typo. Somehow author forgot to include backslash

In the command prompt user should type

`copy SA-Eventgen C:\Splunk\etc\apps\SA-Eventgen /O /X /E /H /K`

NOT

`copy SA-Eventgen C:\Splunketcapps\SA-Eventgen /O /X /E /H /K`